# Blackjack aces sequence

Tags: r, sequence

I have a sequence say: 11, 11, 6, 4, 11, 10, 6,... which simulates the following possible card values for a player's hand in blackjack.

When the sum of these numbers accumulates to 11 or greater, I am trying to make each value of 11 which occurs after this point equal to 1.

Where the cumulative sum is: 11, 22, 28, 32,...

Desired outcome: 11, 1, 6, 4, 1, 10, 6,...

Here is what I have been unsuccessfully trying with:

```
nphand = c(11,11,6,4,11,10,6)
v=cumsum(nphand)
p=v[v<=11]

for (i in (length(p)+1):length(nphand)){
    if (nphand[i]==11){
        nphand[i]==1
    }
}
```

Any help and/or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your codes are working well. The only thing you need to change is that change double equal symbol by single one at the second part. I mean use  nphand[i]=1   instead of  nphand[i]==1.

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
nphand = c(11,11,6,4,11,10,6)
v=cumsum(nphand)
p=v[v<=11]

for (i in 1:length(nphand)){
  cards <- nphand[1:i]
  elevens <- cards[-1] %in% 11
  if(sum(cards)>=11 &  sum(elevens) >=1){
    cards[which(elevens) +1] <- 1
  }
  nphand[1:i] <- cards
}



 > nphand
    [1] 11  1  6  4  1 10  6
```

This looks like it is dependent on the first card being 11. The solution below should work regardless:

```
nphand = c(2,11,6,4,11,10,6)
v=cumsum(nphand)
p=v[v<=11]

for (i in 1:length(nphand)){
  cards <- nphand[1:i]
  elevens <- cards %in% 11
  if(sum(cards)>=11 &  sum(elevens) >=1){
    cards[which(elevens[-1]) + 1] <- 1
  }
  nphand[1:i] <- cards
}
```